# Sorting an array - C language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have tried to write a sorting function `sort(int *buffer, int array[], int size)` which works in a way similar to the insertion sort - it takes the first element from the array, sets it as the first element of the buffer and then checks whether or not the next value showing up in the array is greater than the last value stored in the buffer. If yes, it keeps swapping the two elements until everything is in its place. This is my minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *buffer, int array[], int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buffer[i] = array[i];
        while(i >= 1 && buffer[i] < buffer[i-1]) {
            int tmp = buffer[i-1];
            buffer[i-1] = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] = tmp;

            printf("i = %d i: %d, i -1 : %d \n",i, buffer[i], buffer[i-1]);
            i--;
        }

    }
}

int main(void) {
    int array[3] = {4,3,2};
    int buffer[3];
    sort(buffer, array, 3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d", buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

However, the output of this program is `222` 
To be honest, I don't see how it's even possible that three identical elements got placed in the buffer. 
What can have gone wrong?

Comment: You're modifying `i` inside the while loop.

Comment: You’re using the same variable for both your loops.

Comment: This was so simple - I don't know how I can have missed that. Thanks, this actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable for the inner while cycle and for the outer for loop. Use a different variable and copy the value of `i` to it in each iteration of the for.